# Can't connect my HTML-website Subdomain to my main domain on GCP & Google Domains

Tags: html, css, web, google-cloud-platform

Title says it all. 

My website currently is:

 
- bought on google domains

- hosted on GCP

- https verified by DNS on Cloudfare

 
My problem is that my website www.example.com works but I can't manage to make example.com work. I tried  point to point my naked domain A-record to the IP address 174.129.25.170(as mentioned here http://wwwizer.com/naked-domain-redirect ) BUT it didn't work. 
 
Any idea what I can do to make example.com work? Thanks :) 
[image]

Comment: When you say "doesn't work", do you mean the domain name doesn't resolve, or the server doesn't understand the request? In other words, what happens when you ping www.example.com and example.com?

Comment: Hi @SanderSluis ; thanks for your message.
I found my solution.
I needed to add this in Cloudfront and not Google domains... thanks for your help!